# Too many edits - You have already edited 5 of your own posts today

Tags: support

I am seeing this message after I've re-added appropriate tags to my migrated posts:

> Too many edits
>
> You have already edited 5 of your own posts today (not including very recent posts). Further edits are not allowed until tomorrow.
>
> Please contact a moderator if you require assistance.

Is it something normal to be happening? The 5 posts is not a really high number. Do I have to wait till tomorrow to correct few things then? Just double checking.

Comment: If you post some modified text in either comments or answers, along with a request that others put the edits in for you, I imagine there would be people who would help you out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129634/reconcile-the-5-edits-limit-with-a-large-set-of-updates-of-ones-old-answers/171960#171960), the number of edits you're allowed per day depends on your reputation.

You're running into this issue because of the sudden flood of migrated questions which need editing, which is an unusual scenario.

It does appear to be the normal, expected behavior, though.